# databinding angularJS and HAML : substring

Tags: angularjs, sass, substring, haml

I have variable coming form angularJS to haml , I want to substring it and delete a part from it, the varibale is a date with this format :

> 2018-05-07 08:48:35 UTC

anyone can help how to delete the "UTC" part ?

here is the haml part :

```
.directive-report-images{ ng_show: 'conditionIsChecked && fragment._parentConditionChecked' }
  .row
    .col-md-4
      .title
        %h5.black {{ fragment.title }}
    .col-md-8
      %report_fragment_visibility
      .row{ ng_if: 'fragment.media().length <= 2' }
        .col-md-6.thumbnail{ ng_repeat: "img in fragment.media() | notArchived | orderBy:'order'" }
          %img.pointer{ ng_src: "{{ img.contentUrl() }}", ng_click:'openCarouselModal(img)' }
          %p.image-date {{ img.metadata.date_time_original }}
```

angularJS part :

getImages = ->
    listImage = []

```
for sheet in $scope.report.report_sheets()
  for composed in sheet.report_fragments()
    for fragment in composed.report_fragments()
      if fragment.fragment_type is 'images'
        for media in fragment.media()
          listImage.push media
listImage
```

sass part :

```
  .image-date
    text-align: center
    font-weight: bold
    word-spacing: 10px
    font-size: 12px
    color: #636e72
    margin-top: 5px
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` in your markup

```
{{ img.metadata.date_time_original.replace('UTC','') }}
```

More info of `replace` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)